# how to set tablayout position without triggering onTabSelectedListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

[image]

I have tablayout like that. when this fragment appears, I want to set the tab layout position (that underline) programmatically based on certain condition in the `onCreateView`

I am using the code below, to programmatically move the underline to 'two' tab

```
    lateinit var tabLayout : TabLayout

    override fun onCreateView(): View? {

        tabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.select()
        return View
    }
```

but unfortunately, that `tabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.select()` code, will automatically trigger my `onTabSelectedListener` like the code below

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

             // this part will automatically called

            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }


        })
```

so how to set tablayout position without triggering onTabSelectedListener ?

Java is OK

Comment: you set tab listener before or after `select()`?

Comment: before select() .

Answer (score 1):

**Try this solution. it will help you.**

when you are selecting manually at that time set `addOnTabSelectedListener` null so, the callback will not come. after selecting set `addOnTabSelectedListener`. so it will work normally.

```
TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            };


tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(null);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener);
```

Comment: can we remove `tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(null);`?

Comment: if you remove this line then first-time work perfectly but the second time callback will come.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 private void highLightCurrentTab(int position) {
 for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
 TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
 assert tab != null;
 tab.setCustomView(null);
 tab.setCustomView(adapter.getTabView(i));
}
```

Pass the position here.

Or try this -

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {

 myViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);

  myTabLayout.setScrollPosition(position, 0f, true);
  },   100);
```